# Cannot access newly created folder in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat7

I am new to Tomcat, I installed it successfully and I am trying it out now.

I created a new directory "data" in the /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/ directory and I can see the created directory when I browse this address **"http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/html"**. The problem is I cannot access the data folder that I created by accessing **"http://127.0.0.1:8080/data/"** I get a 404 error with the description "The requested resource is not available".

Comment: Have you put any file in `data` folder?

Comment: Yes I did, its just a test.txt file, I can access that file but I cannot access the root data folder.

Comment: Most web servers need a default page named as `index.*`. The answer of @Reza Goodarzi it's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have noticed there was this line in the log file:

```
INFO: Deploying web application directory data
```

which means the directory is expected to be a web application; but I guess the directory is empty; so, there is actually nothing to be shown. Just put a simple `index.html` file in the directory and you will be able to go to the page using this address: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/data/`